# How to add a numbered list to my Prime number app, and how to include 2 as prime

Tags: java

This is my code so far:

```
package PrimeNumberinRange;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainApp 
{

  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
    int lowerLimit, upperLimit, s3, flag = 0, i, j;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the lower limit :");
    lowerLimit = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the upper limit :");
    upperLimit = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Prime numbers :");

    for (i = lowerLimit; i <= upperLimit; i++)
    {

            for (j = 2; j < i; j++) 
            {

                if (i % j == 0) 
                {
                    flag = 0;
                    break;
                } else 
                {
                    flag = 1;
                }
            }
            if (flag == 1) 
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }

    }//for

  }//main

}//MainApp
```

Obviously I need to include 2 as a prime number but can't find where to fit in the statement. And I'm also looking to have the prime numbers displayed in a list like this:

Enter the lower limit:
1
Enter the upper limit:
10
Prime Numbers:
1. 2
2. 3
3. 5
4. 7

Any other advice or tips is also greatly welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another condition in your if statement:

```
for (i = lowerLimit; i <= upperLimit; i++)
{

        for (j = 2; j < i; j++) 
        {

            if (i % j == 0 && i!=2) 
            {
                flag = 0;
                break;
            } else 
            {
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 1) 
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

 }
```

OR you could create a method that checks whether it's a prime or not.

```
boolean isPrime(int n) {
for(int i=2;i<n;i++) {
    if(n%i==0)
        return false;
}
 return true;
}
```

Now,there are other faster way of doing this, but I hope you got the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about just printing it is the pre-conditions are OK

```
System.out.println("Prime numbers :");
if (upperLimit >= 2) {
  // just print it
  System.out.println("2");
}
```